# How can I pass children fields to a datatable?

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, aura, datatable

I'm looking for a way to make my datatable display records from my current object and children records.

The query i'm running is:

```
List<Account> accounts = [
              SELECT Id, Name, BillingState, (
                       SELECT Id, Name, target_amount__c
                       FROM Targets__r
              )
              FROM Account
              LIMIT 10 ];
```

Now, If i want to show a parent record, i can easily enough set the attribute "fieldName" to "Object__r.Field_Name__c".

But what if i was going the other way around? What if I wanted to display records from a child record (target object in this particular situation)? Is it doable in any way?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question:

what i ended up doing is creating a wrapper class with the fields i am interested in storing and used the fields names in my columns instead of the Salesforce API Names.

so 'fieldName' -> wrapperClass.fieldName

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how you can display the parent and child records in the table.

HTML::

```
<template>
        <div class="slds-box slds-theme–default">             
                <table class="slds-table slds-table_cell-buffer slds-table_bordered slds-table_striped">
                        <thead>
                                <tr class="slds-line-height_reset">
                                        <th class="" scope="col">
                                                AccountId
                                        </th>
                                        <th class="" scope="col">
                                                Account Name
                                        </th>
                                        <th class="" scope="col">
                                                Account Phone
                                        </th>
                                        <th class="" scope="col">
                                                Website
                                        </th>
                                </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                                <template for:each={listOfAccount} for:item="acc">
                                        <tr class="slds-hint-parent" key={acc.Id}>
                                                <td>
                                                        <div class="slds-cell-wrap">{acc.Id}</div>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                        <div class="slds-cell-wrap">{acc.Name}</div>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                        <div class="slds-cell-wrap">{acc.Phone}</div>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                        <div class="slds-cell-wrap">{acc.Website}</div>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                        <div class="slds-cell-wrap">
                                                                <lightning-button data-id={acc.Id} variant="brand" label="+" 
                                                                        onclick={handleClick}></lightning-button>
                                                        </div>
                                                </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr key={acc.Id}>
                                                <td colspan="4"> 
                                                        <template if:true={acc.Contacts}>
                                                                <div data-id={acc.Id} class="slds-hide" style="box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #888888;box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px gray; margin: 10px; padding: 10px;">
                                                                        Contacts:
                                                                        <table
                                                                                class="slds-table slds-table_cell-buffer slds-table_bordered">
                                                                                <thead>
                                                                                        <tr class="slds-line-height_reset">
                                                                                                <th class="" scope="col">
                                                                                                        ContactId
                                                                                                </th>
                                                                                                <th class="" scope="col">
                                                                                                        Contact Name
                                                                                                </th>
                                                                                                <th class="" scope="col">
                                                                                                        Contact Email
                                                                                                </th>
                                                                                                <th class="" scope="col">
                                                                                                        Contact Phone
                                                                                                </th>
                                                                                        </tr>
                                                                                </thead>
                                                                                <tbody>
                                                                                        <template for:each={acc.Contacts} for:item="con">
                                                                                                <tr class="slds-hint-parent" key={con.Id}>
                                                                                                        <td>
                                                                                                                <div class="slds-cell-wrap">{con.Id}</div>
                                                                                                        </td>
                                                                                                        <td>
                                                                                                                <div class="slds-cell-wrap">{con.Name}</div>
                                                                                                        </td>
                                                                                                        <td>
                                                                                                                <div class="slds-cell-wrap">{con.Email}</div>
                                                                                                        </td>
                                                                                                        <td>
                                                                                                                <div class="slds-cell-wrap">{con.Phone}</div>
                                                                                                        </td>
                                                                                                </tr>
                                                                                        </template>
                                                                                </tbody>
                                                                        </table>
                                                                </div>
                                                        </template>
                                                </td>
                                        </tr>
                                </template>
                        </tbody>
                </table>
        </div>        
</template>
```

JS::

```
import { LightningElement, track, wire } from 'lwc';
import getListOfAccounts from '@salesforce/apex/CustomHTMLTableController.getAccounts';

import NAME_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Account.Name';
import REVENUE_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Account.AnnualRevenue';
import INDUSTRY_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Account.Industry';
export default class CustomHTMLTable extends LightningElement {
    @track listOfAccount = [];
    @track error;
    @track objectApiName = 'Account';
    @track fields = [NAME_FIELD, REVENUE_FIELD, INDUSTRY_FIELD];

    @wire(getListOfAccounts)
    accounts({ data, error }) {
        if (data) {
            this.listOfAccount = data;
            this.error = undefined;
        } else if (error) {
            this.error = JSON.stringify(error);
            this.listOfAccount = undefined;
        }
    }

    handleClick(event) {
        const rowId = event.target.dataset.id;
        let btnlabel = event.target.label;
        if(btnlabel == "+"){
            this.template.querySelector(`lightning-button[data-id="${rowId}"]`).label = "-";
        } else {
            this.template.querySelector(`lightning-button[data-id="${rowId}"]`).label = "+";
        }
        this.template.querySelector(`div[data-id="${rowId}"]`).classList.toggle('slds-hide');      
       
    }    
}
```

APEX Class::

```
global class CustomHTMLTableController {
    
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    global static List<Account> getAccounts(){
        List<Account> listOfAccounts = new List<Account>();
        listOfAccounts = [SELECT Id, Name, Phone, Website,(SELECT Id, Name, EMail, Phone, AccountId FROM Contacts) FROM Account LIMIT 5];
        return listOfAccounts;
    }
}
```

Output::
[image]